# How to reuse a data batch from iterator.get_next()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm implementing an algorithm involving alternating optimization. That is, at each iteration, the algorithm fetches a data batch, and uses the data batch to optimize two losses *sequentially*. My current implementation with `tf.data.Dataaset` and `tf.data.Iterator` is something like this (which is indeed incorrect as detailed below):

```
data_batch = iterator.get_next()
train_op_1 = get_train_op(data_batch)
train_op_2 = get_train_op(data_batch)

for _ in range(num_steps):
    sess.run(train_op_1)
    sess.run(train_op_2)
```

Note that the above is incorrect because each call of `sess.run` will advance the iterator to get next data batch. So `train_op_1` and `train_op_2` are indeed using different data batches.

I cannot do something like `sess.run([train_op_1, train_op_2])` either, because the two optimization steps need to be sequential (i.e., the 2nd optimization step depends on the latest variable value by the 1st optimization step.)

I'm wondering is there any way to somehow "freeze" the iterator, so that it won't advance in a `sess.run` call?

Comment: Can't you make two iterators over the same Dataset?

Comment: @honza_p you are correct. It looks like a good solution to use two iterators with a feedable iterator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something similar so that is part of my code stripped from some unnecessary stuff. It does a bit more as it has train and validation iterators, but you should get the idea of using `is_keep_previous` flag. Basically passed as `True` it fill force reuse of the previous value of the iterator, in case of `False` it will get new value.

```
iterator_t = ds_t.make_initializable_iterator()
iterator_v = ds_v.make_initializable_iterator()

iterator_handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[], name="iterator_handle")
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(iterator_handle, 
                                               iterator_t.output_types,
                                               iterator_t.output_shapes)

def get_next_item():
  # sometimes items need casting
  next_elem = iterator.get_next(name="next_element")
  x, y = tf.cast(next_elem[0], tf.float32), next_elem[1]
  return x, y  

def old_data():
        # just forward the existing batch
        return inputs, target

is_keep_previous = tf.placeholder_with_default(tf.constant(False),shape=[], name="keep_previous_flag")

inputs, target =  tf.cond(is_keep_previous, old_data, new_data)

with tf.Session() as sess:
 sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),tf.local_variables_initializer()])        
 handle_t = sess.run(iterator_t.string_handle())
 handle_v = sess.run(iterator_v.string_handle())
 # Run data iterator initialisation
 sess.run(iterator_t.initializer)
 sess.run(iterator_v.initializer)
 while True:
   try:
     inputs_, target_ = sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle: handle_t, is_keep_previous:False})
     print(inputs_, target_)
     inputs_, target_ = sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle: handle_t, is_keep_previous:True})
     print(inputs_, target_)
     inputs_, target_ = sess.run([inputs, target], feed_dict={iterator_handle: handle_v})
     print(inputs_, target_)
   except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
     # now we know we run out of elements in the validationiterator
     break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use control dependencies when building the graph for train_op_2 so it can see the updated values of the variables.

Or use eager execution.